# Goldnight Commander and Thatcher Revolt

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I'm not 100% sure what happens if I have a [Goldnight Commander](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Goldnight%20Commander) on the battlefield and play a [Thatcher Revolt](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Thatcher%20Revolt). Do all three 1/1 red human tokens enter the battlefield at once, giving each of them +3/+3 (along with all creatures already on the battlefield)? Or does the first one get +3/+3, the second one +2/+2 and the last one only +1/+1?

I'm assuming the former, but it would be great if someone could confirm.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All three of your Thatchers will get +3/+3.  They do enter the battlefield simultaneously, and in the process of Thatcher Revolt resolving, Goldnight Commander will trigger three separate times.  By the time you reach the point of going to resolve each of the three Goldnight Commander triggers on the stack, Thatcher Revolt has long since finished resolving, and all your Thatchers are present on the battlefield, queueing up for their Giant Growths!

Answer (score 6):

According to the comprensive rules on triggered abilities:

> 603.3b If multiple abilities have triggered since the last time a player received priority, each player, in APNAP order, puts triggered abilities he or she controls on the stack in any order he or she chooses. (See rule 101.4.) Then the game once again checks for and resolves state-based actions until none are performed, then abilities that triggered during this process go on the stack. This process repeats until no new state-based actions are performed and no abilities trigger. Then the appropriate player gets priority.

and:

> 603.6a Enters-the-battlefield abilities trigger when a permanent enters the battlefield. These are written, "When [this object] enters the battlefield, ..." or "Whenever a [type] enters the battlefield, ..." Each time an event puts one or more permanents onto the battlefield, all permanents on the battlefield (including the newcomers) are checked for any enters-the-battlefield triggers that match the event.

This means that when the tokens come into play at the same time, each individual trigger from Goldnight Commander goes on the stack one after another, and you resolve one at a time. Each one will give all your creatures +1/+1.

To sum up, **all the tokens will get +3/+3!** Remember, the triggered abilities go on the stack after Thatcher Revolt finishes resolving, at which point you already have all the tokens in play!